# Using a Swift protocol in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates

I'm working on converting my project from Objective-c to Swift, and a Swift class I'm using, I have a `protocol` I'm trying to access in an Objective-c class. My problem is, the `delegate` is not accessible in the objective-c class. Here is my swift class:

```
protocol RateButtonDelegate {
    func rateButtonPressed(rating: Int)
}

class RateButtonView: UIView {


    var delegate: RateButtonDelegate?

    var divider1: UIView!
    var divider2: UIView!
}
```

When I look at the `MyProject-Swift.h` file, I don't see the `delegate`:

```
@interface RateButtonViewTest : UIView
@property (nonatomic) UIView * divider1;
@property (nonatomic) UIView * divider2;
@end
```

and when I try to use `rateButtonView.delegate` in my Objective-c class, I get a compiler error.

Anyone know the issue? How do access a Swift protocol in Objective-c?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to mark your protocol with the `@objc` attribute for it to be accessible from Objective-C:

```
@objc protocol RateButtonDelegate {
    func rateButtonPressed(rating: Int)
}
```

[This page from Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_86) covers the issue.

Comment: You're a life saver. Thank you!