# How do I respond to swift delegate in my Objective C Project using Cocoa Pods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates

I was attempting to use [this swift pod](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/PIDatePicker) in my objective-c project. I got the compiler to recognize the class by using #import "PIDatePicker-swift.h" in my objective-c MyClass.m file, and was able to create a PIDatePicker object, but [the method Apple recommends for conforming to the swift protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html), in this case  PIDatePickerDelegate, gave me the error: "No type of protocol named PIDatePickerDelegate."

Comment: My god... not only is your question totally unclear, but as your self-answer indicates, **you KNOW it's a duplciate** of [Using a Swift protocol in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26471898/2792531)...

Comment: This is a common problem users of Cocoa pods will encounter when mixing Swift and Objective C code. It's not exactly a duplicate because I am using a Pod and the answer linked does not. So, I reasoned that a new question was warranted; this is why I added, "However, if you're working with a swift podfile, as I was, it's not always clear what to do, and so I am posting this for any others who may be in the same fix" to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The fix for this was adding the following @objc tag to the swift file protocol definition, in this case, PIDatePickerDelegate.swift:

```
    public protocol PIDatePickerDelegate {
    func pickerView(pickerView: PIDatePicker, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
}
```

Just changed the above to:

```
@objc public protocol PIDatePickerDelegate {
    func pickerView(pickerView: PIDatePicker, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
}
```

This is also answered here:

[Using a Swift protocol in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471898/using-a-swift-protocol-in-objective-c)

However, if you're working with a swift podfile, as I was, it's not always clear what to do, and so I am posting this for any others who may be in the same fix. [The troubleshooting section of Apple's Using Swift with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) docs also has this line:

- To be accessible and usable in Objective-C, a Swift class must be a descendant of an Objective-C class or it must be marked @objc.