# How to reference Swift protocol from Objective-C header

Tags: objective-c, swift

I can't reference `SomeSwiftProtocol` from my Objective-C header files.

Do you know how can it be done?

---

My protocol is defined like this:

```
@objc protocol SomeSwiftProtocol : class {
  func someFunc()
}
```

It is well defined (not [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471898/using-a-swift-protocol-in-objective-c)) because I can use it from `.m` files by importing the Swift bridging header:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

But that import is not found when I put it in `.h` files.

For example, this is `SomeClass.h`:

```
// This import is not found...
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"

// ...so the protocol is not found
@interface SomeClass : UIView<SomeSwiftProtocol>
@end
```

Comment: Does this work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28329497/1187415 ?

Comment: You probably have an import loop (Swift -> bridging header -> SomeClass.h -> Swift),  – a forward declaration of the protocol, such as shown in the answer Martin links to, should work.

Comment: I tried with a forward declaration of the protocol in the header, but I get this warning there: `Cannot find protocol definition for 'SomeSwiftProtocol'`.