# Add Swift protocol conformance to Objective-C header and make it public

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've read along [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761658/how-to-reference-swift-protocol-from-objective-c-header?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670431/how-to-prevent-circular-reference-when-swift-bridging-header-imports-a-file-that) about conforming to Swift protocols in Objective-C headers, and I'm not quite getting the behaviour I want - I'm also looking for a better understanding of how this all works. Here's my scenario.

I have a protocol in Swift:

### PersonalDetailsProtocol.swift

```
@objc
protocol PersonalDetailsProtocol {
    func doSomeWork()
}
```

I then have an Objective-C class with a header and implementation file

### RegistrationPersonalDetails.h

```
@protocol PersonalDetailsProtocol; // Forward declare my Swift protocol

@interface RegistrationPersonalDetails : NSObject <PersonalDetailsProtocol>

@end
```

### RegistrationPersonalDetails.m

```
#import "RegistrationPersonalDetails.h"

@implementation RegistrationPersonalDetails

- (void)doSomeWork {
    NSLog(@"Working...");
}
@end
```

At this point everything compiles, although there is a warning in the `RegistrationPersonalDetails.h` file stating `Cannot find protocol definition for 'PersonalDetailsProtocol'`. Other than that warning, the issue I'm facing is I can't publicly call the `doSomeWork` method on an instance of `RegistrationPersonalDetails`.

The call site in Swift would look something like:

```
let personalDetails = RegistrationPersonalDetails()
personalDetails.doSomeWork()
```

but I get an error stating:

```
Value of type 'RegistrationPersonalDetails' has no member 'doSomeWork'
```

I get that the method isn't public, because it's not declared in the header file. But I didn't think it should have to be as long as the protocol conformance is public i.e. declared in the header file.

Can anyone point me on the right path here and offer an explanation? Or is this even possible? I can obviously rewrite the protocol in ObjC, but I just always try to add new code as Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure objective-c, you cannot make a class conform to a protocol without importing it in the header. To make the use of a protocol private, the conformance shouldn't be declared in the header. It remains possible to call such a method using a cast however, but it should be done with caution because it's a little bit unsafe :

```
if ([anInstance respondToSelector:@selector(myProtocolMethod)])
    [(id<MyProtocol>)anInstance myProtocolMethod];
```

I'm not familiar with Swift, but I think you can do the same this way (or something close to it) :

```
 if let conformingInstance = anInstance as? MyProtocol
     conformingInstance.myProtocolMethod
```

EDIT : To complete my first assertion, forward declarations can still be used in the header when you need to declare a method receiving or returning an instance conforming to that protocol :

```
@SomeProtocol;

// This is not possible
@interface MyClass : NSObject <SomeProtocol>         

// But this is possible
@property (nonatomic) id<SomeProtocol> someProperty;
-(void) someMethod:(id<SomeProtocol>)object; 
@end
```

In this [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c) Apple clearly said that :

> Forward declarations of Swift classes and protocols can be used only
> as types for method and property declarations.

So it seems that the rule is the same whatever the protocol is an Objective-c protocol or a Swift protocol.

Comment: When you say "importing it in the header" do you mean actually using `#import` as opposed to forward declaring? In that case then you could never use a Swift protocol in a  header file, even as a function parameter.

Comment: Ahhh thank you! I couldn't find documentation on the issue, but you've cleared it up for me!